I cant get a declarative macro to work rust
I am diving into rust macros and i wanted to try something but i just cant get it to work
macro_rules! expr_enum {
    (base($ch:expr)) => {
        {
            let expression = Enum::Base($ch);
            expression
        }
    };

    (not($inner:tt)) => {
        {
            let inner_expr = expr_enum!($inner);
            let pointer_inner = Box::new(inner_expr);
            Enum::Not(pointer_inner)
        }   
    };
}
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Enum {
    Base(char),
    Not(Box<Enum>),
    And(Vec<Enum>),
    Or(Vec<Enum>),
}

fn main() {
    let expr1:Enum = expr!(base('A'));
    let expr2:Enum = expr!(not(base('A')));

    println!("{:?}",expr1);
    println!("{:?}",expr2);
    println!("{:?}",expr3);
    println!("{:?}",expr4);
}
#[derive(Clone, Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum Enum {
    Base(char),
    Not(Box<Enum>),}

fn main() {
    let expr1:Enum = expr!(base('A'));
    let expr2:Enum = expr!(not(base('A')));

    println!("{:?}",expr1);
    println!("{:?}",expr2);
}

I tried watching a couple of videos, read compiler errors, watched university presentations, read some info online here and there and whatever i did there were aways some errors. I made it work with only the base but when I tried implementing the not even the base was underlined and something wasnt working.
I am trying to successfully make a declarative macro that takes the things its given and return an object from Enum
I tried changing the variables attributes with different ones like expr, tt, literal, item and probably others but i just cant make it to work.

Please include a Minimal Reproducible Example (your code has other unrelated errors), and the full error from cargo check (not your IDE).

Well, base('A') is not one tt (it's two), what did you expect?

What is the specific error?

Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?.

Your first macro arm is correct. You can specify tokens to match, and you can even add parentheses, as you did.
The error is in your second arm. You are trying to match something like not(base('A')) to not($inner:tt), which is incorrect. The reason being that base('A') is simply not a single tt.
The most primitive solution to your problem would look something like this:
macro_rules! expr_enum {
    ( base ( $ch:expr ) ) => {
        Enum::Base($ch)
    };

    ( not ( $inner:tt ( $ch:expr ) ) ) => {
        Enum::Not(
            Box::new(
                expr_enum!($inner($ch))
            )
        )
    };
}

You must understand that base('A') is not a tt. It is in fact a tt tt expr tt. Each token matches to a tt.
But, since you want parentheses, you can specify them even further: tt ( expr ).
Now, by capturing a list of arguments inside the second arm, you will be able to nest not directives with arbitrary depth.
macro_rules! expr_enum {
    ( base( $ch:expr ) ) => {
        Enum::Base($ch)
    };

    ( not ( $inner:tt ( $($args:tt)* ) ) ) => {
        Enum::Not(
            Box::new(
                expr_enum!($inner($($args)*))
            )
        )
    };
}

Explanation:
The pattern not( $inner:tt ( $($args:tt)* ) ) will match an outer not directive that has a nested inner directive with arbitrary arguments. After this, it will call itself, but this time, the inner directive will become the outer directive, and it does this until a base directive is found.
An example would illustrate this better:

not(base('A')): the not keyword and the ( token are matched by the first part of the macro pattern. Then the nested base keyword and the following ( token are matched by $inner:tt (. Then, whatever is inside inner, aka base is matched by $($args:tt)*. This syntax means zero or more tokens. Finally, the remaining ) tokens are matched.

not(not(not(base('A')))): similar to the first example, but the not directives are nested deeper. The first not( is matched by the first part of the macro pattern. Then the second not( is matched by $inner:tt (. Then, whatever is inside the second not is matched by $($args:tt)*. Finally, the remaining ) tokens are matched.


The second macro arm calls itself with $inner($($args)*) as the arguments. In the case of not(not(not(base('A')))), the inner not(not(base('A'))) would be passed. Then not(base('A')), and finally base('A'), completing the recursion.
